# Library catalog search sql statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, shared-libraries, where-clause

I want the user to select the search criteria for his books here is code, suggestions please!!

```
String keyword=Textbox1.Text; //User types keyword
String userCriteria=Textbox2.Text;// Can be Title, Author, Subject or ISBN;

String sql="Select * from tableBooks WHERE '"+keyword+"' like '%"+userCriteria+"'%";
```

How to let the user select their own criteria for searching the database?

Comment: I don't want to sound mean.. but I would definitely pick up a book on [tag:C#] and [tag:SQL]. Your eventual query will make no sense.

Comment: Plus you should lookup SQL injection attacks. Writing code like that is setting yourself up for a big fail.

Comment: use store procedure to search data.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need a better way to build your query.
You do not directly take input from the user without certain measure of checking or filtering and put it in your query. That would expose your application to sql injections.
Use SQL parameters. 
Try this link as reference :http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

example :

```
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from tableBooks WHERE @Field LIKE @Value", connection))
        {
        //
        // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
        //
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Field", Textbox1.Text)); // I do not recommend using a textbox and letting the user write anything. You have to limit his choices by the fields in your table. Use a dropdownlist and limit his choices by meaningful fields in your "tableBooks" table.
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Value", Textbox2.Text));
        //
        // Read in the SELECT results.
        //
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //GET YOUR BOOK
        }
        }
```

Please notice my comments :

// I do not recommend using a textbox and letting the user write anything as a "keyword". You have to limit his choices by the columns in your table. Use a dropdownlist and limit his choices by meaningful choices from your "tableBooks" table.

Answer (score 0):

It is more secure to used parameterized query than the form you use already
you can try this, I think it will help

```
// Declare a connection
            conn =  new 
                SqlConnection("Server=.;DataBase=DataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

            //Create parameterized query
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "Select * from tableBooks WHERE (case @userCriteria when 'Title' then Title when 'Author' then Author when 'Subject' then Subject when 'ISBN' then ISBN else '' end)  LIKE '%'+@keyword+ '%'", conn);
            //Create parameter userCriteria
            SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@userCriteria";
            param.Value         = userCriteria;
            //Create parameter keyword
            SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@keyword";
            param.Value         = userCriteria;

            // add new parameter to command object
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            // get data stream
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // write each record
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                //Get data
            }
```